# Сколько элементов может содержать в себе PHP-массив и на что это влияет?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Для наглядности приведу пример:

```
$query = "
          SELECT
                id
          FROM
                files
          WHERE
                act = 1
         ";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    $filesIDs = [];

    while ($files = $result->fetch_row()[0])
    {
        $filesIDs[$files] = '';
    }
#...
```

Предположим, что в базе 700 файлов, но что если их будет 100.000 ?

1) Насколько такой код способен "тормозить" систему, если выполняется на каждой странице для каждого пользователя сайта?
2) Каковы последствия хранения в файле сессии пользователя: `$_SESSION[$files] = '';` ?

Comment: На расход памяти влияет и сам цикл 100к операций будет тормозить. В сессию ... будет мегабайтый файл каждой сессии. И опять же его каждый раз скрипт будет поднимать в память при каждом обращении. В общем лучше этого избежать. Нет смысла доставать откуда либо значения, все из которых не нужны для выполнения конкретной работы. Если нужен кеш в памяти так и стоит задействовать специализированные средства типа memcached

Comment: @Mike или может Redis в данном случае? есть разница?

Answer (score 1):

Как такого числового лимита на кол-во элементов в массиве (размер массива) нет.
Он, размер массива, ограничен лишь объемом имеющейся памяти: сколько памяти отведено скрипту.
Изначально скрипту дается 128МВ памяти, но этот показатель можно менять, используя команду `memory_limit()` (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)